# How do I access specfic JSON data from Rotten Tomatoes' API

Tags: android, json, rotten-tomatoes

I'm trying to develop a quick app that will return the upcoming movies and their abridged cast from this site: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Upcoming_Movies. However I am unsure on how to access the latest movies along with the abridged cast. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here as JSON is a little confusing for me.

I have used [How to request movie data from Rotten Tomatoes using their JSON API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172735/how-to-request-movie-data-from-rotten-tomatoes-using-their-json-api) to help me thus far, but I want to be able to list the film and the cast in the format "The Hangover: Bradley Cooper, etc..." What I have so far is this

```
if (response != null)
{
    try
    {
        // convert the String response to a JSON object,
        // because JSON is the response format Rotten Tomatoes uses
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

        // fetch the array of movies in the response
        JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

        // add each movie's title to an array
        String[] movieTitles = new String[movies.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
            movieTitles[i] = movie.getString("title");
            JSONArray cast = movie.getJSONArray("abridged_cast");
            String[] castmembers = new String[cast.length()];
            for(int j =0; j<cast.length();j++){


            }
        }

        // update the UI
        refreshMoviesList(movieTitles);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "Failed to parse the JSON response!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you want your output format to be as follows:Matrix: Keane Reeves, Lawrence fishburne,.....
Assuming that you are getting the right data from your json, the following will do:

```
   // add each movie's title to an array
    String[] movieTitles = new String[movies.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
        movieTitles[i] = movie.getString("title") + ":";
        JSONArray cast = movie.getJSONArray("abridged_cast");
        String[] castmembers = new String[cast.length()];
        for(int j =0; j<cast.length();j++){
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　movieTitles[i] += castmembers[j];
                if( j < (cast.length()-1)){
                     movieTitles[i] += ",";
                 } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was correct for the most part, just needed to initialise the array by doing     JSONObject name = cast.getJSONObject(j);
       castmembers[j] = name.getString("name"); Thanks for the help!